# Build options: Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cross-platform

I am running opencv on iOS but some of the commands give linker error `Undefined symbols for architecture i386`. I am trying to change the Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C in build options of the xcode project but there is no option for clang. The only option is the selected one `Default Compiler Apple LLVM 5.0`. Does anyone know how to get through this?

Comment: This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387596/compiling-opencv-2-4-on-a-64-bit-mac-in-xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Apple LLVM 5.0" is otherwise known as "clang", which is the C, C++ and Objective-C front-end for LLVM.

From the [clang webpage](http://clang.llvm.org/):

> The goal of the Clang project is to create a new C, C++, Objective C
>   and Objective C++ front-end for the LLVM compiler. You can get and
>   build the source today.

However changing the compiler won't affect your "undefined symbol" error, which is probably because you aren't linking against a "fat library" (an archive that contains multiple architectures for iOS Devices and the iOS Simulator).

Comment: Try adding -lstdc++ or -lc++ flag in other linker flags.

Comment: @chandu No, you shouldn't need that at all.

Comment: are you referencing any project or external framework?