# Getting error for deployment target

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios6, iphone-5

Getting the following error. I have changed the deployment target to 4.3 from 5.0 gives this error. How to solve it with deployment target 4.3?

> clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires
>   iOS 5.0 or later)
>   Command/Applications/Xcode2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: because of this library (libc++) it need iOS 5.0 or later

Comment: But in my project no such lib added

Comment: check in Build Phases --> link binaries with libraries

Comment: This link can help you. It has similar Question as yours..

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14054074/437146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i myself solved the Que. for the below error to remove.

clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires iOS 5.0 or later) to remove this error.

> GoTo BuildSettings. Set c++ standard library to compiler default. The
>   error will get removed surely.