# OpenCV 2.4.3+ with libstdc++ for iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv, c++11

I'm trying to include a recent version of OpenCV into an existing iOS project and am having linker errors because my XCode project is set to use libstdc++ and not libc++ / C++ 11 support.

I have seen several other people who have fixed their errors by enabling libc++. Examples:

- [Linker errors after upgrading Xcode to 4.5.2 and OpenCV to 2.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030546/linker-errors-after-upgrading-xcode-to-4-5-2-and-opencv-to-2-4-3)
- [How to resolve iOS Link errors with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185716/how-to-resolve-ios-link-errors-with-opencv)

However, I NEED to use libstdc++ because I have other 3rd party libraries which are already compiled with the older stdlib (can't be changed). Is there a way to compile OpenCV 2.4.3+ without -stdlib=libc++ ? Are there special flags to pass to CMake? or to the build_framework.py script that comes in the ios folder of the OpenCV source code?

Alternatively, does anyone have a binary version available? It seems all downloadable from OpenCV assume libc++ / C++11.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the source for openCV locate this file:

```
ios/cmake/Modules/Platform/iOS.cmake
```

Change this line:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++ -headerpad_max_install_names -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden")
```

to:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libstdc++ -headerpad_max_install_names -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden")
```

Compile using the python script

```
ios/build_framework.py
```

Then you should be good to go

I have just tried this on 2.4.3 source, swapped in the resulting framework on an existing project, changed the C++ standard library for the project to libstdc++ and it runs fine.

Comment: Yes! That's a pretty easy solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on a project using OpenCV and a 3rd party library which requires libstdc++.

As I just ran into this problem myself, I wanted to share what worked for me.

---

I was able to get OpenCV working by adding "libc++.dylib" to my project.

Build Phases -> "Link Binary with Libraries" -> "+" -> libc++.dylib

For reference, I am using OpenCV 2.4.9 (opencv-2.4.9) from opencv.org.  I compiled it using  the ios platform build_framework.py per the instructions in OpenCV's docs.  No modification necessary.