# Use OpenCV C++ commands within OpenFrameworks Xcode OSX Project

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, openframeworks

I would like to use OpenFrameworks for an OSX application I am building. However, I need to include some existing code that uses C++ OpenCV commands, e.g. cv::imread().

The Xcode linker throws the error `Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "cv::imread(std::string const&, int)`. At first I tried to use the existing OpenCV code that is in ofxOpenCv, then fell back to including the OpenCV framework as I had in previous non-OpenFrameworks projects. Neither approach solved the linking problem.

As far as I can tell, the problem is that OpenCV is compiled with the **libc++** compiler, while OpenFrameworks is compiled with the **libstdc++** compiler.

- [This presentation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53229744/Open-Frameworks-and-OpenCV) shows how to use C++ OpenCV commands within OpenFrameworks, but it is under Windows and not a detailed account.
- [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855894/opencv-2-4-3-with-libstdc-for-ios) implies that OpenCV can be recompiled under libstdc++, but the solution given is for iOS and referenced make file does not exist for OSX/linux.

Is it at all possible to use OpenFrameworks with the OpenCV C++ commands under OSX?

Comment: Can you post to github? Hard to tell without looking at the project/code.

Answer (score 2):

Please use [Kyle McDonald's ofxCv](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv) addon, it's a much nicer interface to opencv from openframeworks. It includes [Utilities](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv/blob/master/libs/ofxCv/src/Utilities.cpp) to convert from `cv::Mat` of ofImage and back for example or [helpers](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv/blob/master/libs/ofxCv/src/Helpers.cpp) to draw `cv::Mat` straight in your of application:

```
#include "testApp.h"

using namespace ofxCv;
using namespace cv;
Mat img;
void testApp::setup() {
    img = imread("yourImage.png");//make sure the path is correct
}

void testApp::update() {
}

void testApp::draw() {
    drawMat(img,0, 0);
}
```

Also, your `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:` error means you probably linked against the x64(64-bit) opencv .dylib files, not the i386(32b-bit) ones.